# CLR Application in Visual Studio 2015 C++ (Unrecognized Code?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr, windows-forms-designer

So, let's get this rolling. I have already created several programs with C++ in the past with the same IDE; Visual Studio, and I have seem to come across a problem where when I'm trying to call the Application namespace, and it just won't recognize it. Maybe I'm doing something silly like forgetting to import or include a namespace, but I'm pretty sure this is correct. I've looked on the main websites that I could, I haven't really found what I was looking for, so I have decided it will help a lot of users like me that are new to C++, but not Visual Studio.

I already know how to setup the Linker in C++, so if that has anything to do with it, not.

If you'd like to see my LibraryWindow.cpp file:

```
#include "LibraryWindow.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

[STAThread]
int Main(array<System::String^>^ args) {

    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();

    LibraryWindow libraryWindow = new LibraryWindow();
    Application::Run(%libraryWindow);

}
```

Mainly, the code above is written from memory.

But again, if you are still unsure what I mean, the namespace "Application" gives a red error sign, and obviously it will compile with errors.

I also feel like there are some dumb thing's I'm doing with the code, so I'm hoping to get it all sorted out in the end.

Comment: Yes, I know I set "using namespace System;" and then "System::String", but that was me debugging the String error I was having before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Application` is not a namespace. It is a class inside of namespace `System::Windows::Forms` ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So, you need to add

```
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
```

before your main, or namespace-qualify every usage of `Application`.

And, in addition to that, you need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. Which can be added via:

Project properties -> Common Properties -> References -> Add New Reference.

Comment: It answered the question, but I still can't get my application to run, because it won't recognize LibraryWindow.h. But I'm just getting started so, soon I'll be helping users with the same problems.

Comment: @VenHayz The `LibraryWindow.h` was being included as if it was local to your project. Since you didn't provide sources to it, I commented out the lines referencing it, when I tried to look for, and test solution for your problem, since I assumed that you have it, locally (which, by all inclusion rules is the same folder as the file that is including it - .cpp file that you posted).